# How to use fmx listview to edit fields loaded from a query

Tags: listview, delphi

Delphi 10.3  Multi device application.

I have a listview binded to a query and displaying fields.
IE. Name, address, phone,etc

I am looking for an example to edit the info in the listview  and save it .

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear exactly what it is that you want to edit.  Is it a) the list of field names that are used to query your database table or b) the field values which are returned by the query?

Comment: Add another tabsheet to the project, and add some Edit controls to the tabsheet. You can also bind these to the query.

Comment: I want to edit the values in the filds. Example:= John  . Edit John to Jon.

Comment: @ nolaspeaker I have some edits on a differnt tab. Problem is on a mobile device I can not scroll the tab so the user can see what they are trying to edit

Comment: @grant1842 Use the OnItemClick event so that when the user taps the entry in the listview, you change the active tab to the one with the edits

Comment: @Dave Nottage . Thank you for that suggestion.